# How can I read and write data about the accelerometer in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a step counter for android. It currently includes four buttons in one activity:
a button to start recording accelerometer data which is stored in an arraylist. The arraylist takes a type Trace, which is a class I created to hold the data of one sensor change. I also have a stop button, and buttons to read or write the data from text file.

This program keeps giving me a NullPointerException on the arraylist and I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry if the indentation is off or the code is unclear, this is a school assignment and I'm on a strict deadline so I have to rush to make the code usable before I can worry about readability or efficiency.

EDIT 2: I no longer get any exceptions, however I still cannot read/write properly. I was able to write to file one successfully, and then somehow it stops functioning.

```
package com.myApp.playpool;

    //imports

public class MainActivityBAK extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

    //global fields (traces is instantiated here as new arraylist)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        acceleration=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.acceleration);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        readButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readButton);
        writeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.writeButton);

        sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

        dataFilePath = getString(R.string.data_file_path);
        acceleration.setText("Current file: " + dataFilePath);

        lastCheck = System.currentTimeMillis();

        defineButtons();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event1) {

        if (running && ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCheck) > 1000)) { 
            acceleration.setText("X: "+event1.values[0]+"\nY: "+event1.values[1]+"\nZ: "+event1.values[2]);
            traces.add(new Trace(System.currentTimeMillis(), event1.values[0], event1.values[1], event1.values[2]));
            lastCheck = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    public void defineButtons() { //defines onClick methods for the buttons

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                traces = new ArrayList<Trace>();
                running = true;
            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                traces = new ArrayList<Trace>();
                running = false;
            }
        });

        readButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    scan = new Scanner(new File(dataFilePath));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    String str = scan.nextLine();
                    String [] strings = str.split(";");
                    double time = Double.parseDouble(strings[0]);
                    float x = Float.parseFloat(strings[0]), y = Float.parseFloat(strings[1]), z = Float.parseFloat(strings [2]);
                    traces.add(new Trace(time, x, y, z));
                }

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        ("Done reading to SD file: '" + dataFilePath + "'"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                scan.close();
            }
        });

        writeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    File file = new File(dataFilePath);
                    print = new PrintWriter(file);
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < traces.size(); i++) {
                    double time = traces.get(i).time;
                    float x = traces.get(i).x, y = traces.get(i).y, z = traces.get(i).z;
                    print.println(time + ";" + x + ";" + y + ";" + z + ";");
                }
                print.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        ("Done writing to SD file: '" + dataFilePath + "'"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

It seems to be crashing in the for loop in the write method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < traces.size(); i++) {
```

Comment: Add the full stack trace. And tell us exactly which line it's crashing on.

Comment: I'm not sure how to post the stack trace, only how to display it in program. It seems to be crashing in the for loop in the write method:      for (int i = 0; i < traces.size(); i++) {                                the traces.size() call is causing a NullPointerException even though I clearly instantiate the arraylist earlier in the code.

Comment: Java sets it to false by default. So it's false until the go button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You are only initializing the `traces` variable if your buttons start or stop are clicked.

If you click the "write" button before that, then the reference is still null.

Answer (score 1):

It looks perhaps like `traces` has not been initialized in either `onSensorChanged()` or in  your `readButton.setOnClickListener`, although it's hard to tell without the full source code or stack trace. If `traces` is a "// global field" then you should probably initialize it where it's declared, like:

```
protected ArrayList<Trace> traces = new ArrayList<Trace>();
```

**EDIT for 2nd Question**

My guess is that using the `File.createNewFile()` method won't work if the file already exists. Maybe try a different approach, like this sample:

```
Writer writer = null;
try {
    OutputStream out = mContext.openFileOutput(dataFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

    for (int i = 0; i < traces.size(); i++) {
        double time = traces.get(i).time;
        float x = traces.get(i).x, y = traces.get(i).y, z = traces.get(i).z;
        writer.write(time + ";" + x + ";" + y + ";" + z + ";");
    }
}
finally {
    if (writer != null) {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my, what a simple mistake... >_> I initialized it globally and that fixed the exception, but I still cannot get it to read/write properly.